# two submit buttons for different form within the same view and controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a view screen that has two different form on it, that will be activated differently. if the first button is clicked, the first form comes up and the user can fill and submit after which he proceed to click the other button to activate the other form which will then be submitted to a different table. I tried giving it different each submit button different name but my controller isn't recognizing the name. any help will be appreciated.
this is my view presently

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" id="head">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="warehouse" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Transaction type</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.vwint0, ViewBag.action_flag == "Create" ? (object)new { @class = "form-control", style = "width : 120px", @maxlength = 10 } : new { @disabled = "disabled", style = "width : 120px" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.vwint0)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="code" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Customer code</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.vwstring1, ViewBag.cus as SelectList, "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update" value="headsub">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" id="details">
        <div class="form-group">
             <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sale sequence number </label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.vwint0, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width : 80px", maxlength = 10 })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Quote sequence</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.vwstring9, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width : 80px", maxlength = 10 })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item code</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.vwstring10, ViewBag.item as SelectList, "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update" value="detailsub">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

In my controller, I tried this but my controller isn't even recognizing the button name.

```
if (update == "headsub")
{
    AR_002_SALES gdoc = new AR_002_SALES();
    gdoc.sale_sequence_number = glay.vwint0;
    gdoc.customer_code = glay.vwstring1;
    gdoc.currency_code = glay.vwstring2;
}
else
{
    AR_002_QUOTE = new AR_002_QUOTE();
    AR_002_QUOTE.sale_sequence_number = glay.vwint0;
    AR_002_QUOTE.quote_sequence = glay.vwstring9;
    AR_002_QUOTE.item_code = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(glay.vwstring10) ? "" : glay.vwstring10;
    AR_002_QUOTE.quote_qty = glay.vwdclarray0[0];
    AR_002_QUOTE.price = glay.vwdclarray0[1];
}
```

Comment: Please can you explain what it is that isn't working?  What do you mean by  'the controller isn't even recognizing the button name', you haven't posted the controller code?

Comment: the submit button is not working, when I click on it, the controller can not detect the value passed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using   `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" id="head">`
use `@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethod", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" ,@id="head" }))`
to submit a form and action method will process that form and does stuff.Similarly you can do for another form also.

In your .cshtml it looks like it will not hit any action method of that controller.